# ECC RAM in GA-G33M-DS2R? Or any Gigabyte/G33M motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility, ecc

I'm looking to retire a server which has 12GB of ECC DDR2 RAM. I'd like to upgrade my multi-purpose machine (firewall, file server, VM host for Windows Home Server, etc.) using the RAM from the server. I was just wondering:

1. Has anyone had experience using ECC RAM in a GA-G33M-DS2R motherboard (or any Gigabyte GA-G33M-XXXX motherboard for that matter)?
2. Has anyone had experience using ECC RAM in a motherboard with a G33M chipset.

I've searched everywhere and found the attitude positive of ECC memory working in a Non-ECC board, but I would like some specific positive feedback before proceeding tonight. I have to kick the entire house offline, which I don't like to do without good reason :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question: NO. The RAM I had was Fully Buffered (Registered), and keyed differently than the slots. That's not to say that unregistered/non-buffered won't work; just that this particular kind won't.

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer spec indicates 8GB max. They also do not mention ECC and any time I have tried ECC in a board that does not specifically indicate either/or the RAM does not function. However, no expeience with this exact board.